# C# Json.Net - How to deserialize complex object

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a JSON encoded string. It looks like this:

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"test","params":["80851851709e01bc9453cced585a7bca","this"],"id":3}

I cannot get access to 'params' with C# for some reason. The object comes back null. Here is the code I am using:

```
public class Access : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string EntryMethod(string json)
    {
        Requests d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Requests>(json);
        return "done";
    }
}
public class Requests
{
    public string jsonrpc { get; set; }
    public string method { get; set; }
    public List<string> param { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: your property is called `param` not `params`. I guess that is the reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of wrong typo, should be:

```
ParamS // Add one more S
```

So, your class should be:

```
public class Requests
{
    public string jsonrpc { get; set; }
    public string method { get; set; }
    public List<string> @params { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Just being pernickety here...but I wouldn't advise using a reserved keyword as a property name. Might be better renamed `Parameters` instead.