# Json decoding not decoding into complex object

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, json.net

So I have a set of classes:

```
public class CallQueueRequest
{
    public string ACK { get; set; }
    public string ERROR { get; set; }
    public Agent AGENT { get; set; }
    public Skill SKILL { get; set; }
    public string TIME { get; set; }
}

public class Agent
{
    public string has_result { get; set; }
    public List<Agents> agents { get; set; }
}

public class Agents
{
    public string display_name { get; set; }
    public string time_in_state { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string callstakentoday { get; set; }
    public string avaya_skill_num { get; set; }
}

public class Skill
{
    public string has_result { get; set; }
    public string num_skills { get; set; }
    public List<Skills> skills { get; set; }
}

public class Skills
{
    public string display_name { get; set; }
    public string avaya_skill_num { get; set; }
    public string callsinqueue { get; set; }
    public string callstoday { get; set; }
    public string abantoday { get; set; }
    public string lwt { get; set; }
    public string ewt { get; set; }
    public string servicelvl { get; set; }
    public string avgspeedans { get; set; }
    public string talktime { get; set; }
}
```

And I have this Json:

```
{
    "ACK":"SUCCESS",
    "ERROR":null,
    "AGENT":{
        "has_results":1,
        "agents":[
            {
                "display_name":"John Doe",
                "time_in_state":"378",
                "state":"Acd",
                "callstakentoday":null,
                "avaya_skill_num":"81"
            },
            {
                "display_name":"Jane Joe",
                "time_in_state":"220",
                "state":"Acd",
                "callstakentoday":null,
                "avaya_skill_num":"81"
            }
        ]
    },
    "SKILL":{
        "has_results":1,
        "num_skills":1,
        "skills":[
            {
                "display_name":"QueueName",
                "avaya_skill_num":"81",
                "callsinqueue":"1",
                "callstoday":"29",
                "abandtoday":"1",
                "lwt":"74",
                "ewt":"223",
                "servicelvl":"86",
                "avgspeedans":"35",
                "talktime":"873"
            }
        ]
    },
    "TIME":1355864270
}
```

I am using this code:

```
object qr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
```

This does not seem to be converting from Json to the complex class properly. Can someone assist me with this? I think its just a small mistake.

Comment: Do you get an error ? If not, what is the result ?

Comment: Serialize a `CallQueueRequest`, view that json, adjust accordingly.  Lather-rinse-repeat.

Comment: No Error. What happens is qr.ChildrenTokens[0] is the ACK, [1] is ERROR (both are good) but then [2]'s value is the entire AGENT json collection. So instead of being able to go to qr.ChildrenTokens[2].ChildrenTokens[0] to get John Doe's info, I have to do like regex inside of [2].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find some info on what I'm trying to do. If anyone finds this question, [here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711407/c-sharp-json-net-how-to-deserialize-complex-object)

Comment: I fail to see how this is the answer. Could you maybe explain it for future people who come across this?

Comment: I was doing this:
object qr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

I needed to be doing this:
CallQueueRequest cq = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CallQueueRequest>(jsonObject);